# Ionic jspdf error cannot Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jspdf'

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, jspdf

Commands I used:

`npm install dom-to-image --save`
`npm install @types/dom-to-image --save`
`npm install jspdf --save`
`npm install @types/jspdf --save`

My Code:

```
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
import { File, IWriteOptions } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';`
```

Resulting error:

> [ng] ERROR in
>   ./src/app/trail-balance-details/trail-balance-details.page.ts [ng]
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jspdf' in
>   'E:\ionic4\Accounting\src\app\trail-balance-details'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using material-table, you need to upgrade it to the latest. This issue has been fixed on 1.63.1 version. Please use this command for doing so,

```
npm uninstall material-table
npm i material-table
```

Comment: thanks. by the way i have used PHP Script and ionic inappbrowser to solve that problem.